# js file in Grails project. Problem

Tags: javascript, grails

for example, I create .gsp page:

```
<html>
<head>
<g:javascript>
alert("Текст сообщения")
</g:javascript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and write some text in cyrillic - all work fine, rezult: alert window "Текст сообщения", but, when i create gsp page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'js/resources/css',file:'ext-all.css')}" />
<g:javascript src="test.js"></g:javascript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and connect to the page test.js file:

```
alert("Тестовое сообщение");
```

i have a problem, result: alert window with text: `"???????"`

I think the problem is that the Grails does not properly handle character encoding External js file.

What should I do? please help

Comment: I do this: in my IDE STS -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> text file encoding -> change cp1251 on UTF-8. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried setting the charset attribute to

```
<g:javascript src="test.js" charset="UTF-8"></g:javascript>
```

(*and/or changing whatever the encoding in your file is*)